# When Jenkins deploy: chmod: changing permissions of '*' operation not permitted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

I want to setup jenkins to deploy PHP code.

Let's say we have three users in system: `www-data` (Apache), `tomcat` (jenkins) and `user` (me).

I have added `jenkins` and `user` to `www-data` group. 
Existing code (that already running on server and should be overwritten by `tomcat`) own by `user` and belongs to `www-data` group and has `775` permission.

But when I run jenkins and doing `chmod -R 775 *` I get:

`chmod: changing permissions of ‘LICENSE.md’: Operation not permitted`

But permissions already `775` and again `tomcat` in  `www-data` group.

Any thought what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If jenkins (tomcat) does not own the file(s), it will not be permitted to change the ownership regardless of whether the permissions are currently set to the same value.

Comment: Even if tomcat in the group that owns file? Seems I don't understand permissions in linux well.